# What is the type of + function in Clojure (or any other Lisp)?

Tags: clojure, lisp

I understand that Lisps are (usually) dynamically typed, but I guess their values still have types. Functions are values in lisps, so I wonder what is the type of function `+`?

`List of numbers -> number` seemed most likely, so I tried `(+ '(2 3))` and `(+ [2 3])` in Clojure, but neither worked.

Is it possible to query the type of a value (or expression) in Clojure REPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite a complex type that is tricky to define formally for a number of reasons:

- It's a **multi-arity function** (accepts an variable number of parameters). Note that this is *different* from a function that takes a single parameter which is a list of numbers. If you want to use `+` on a list of numbers you need to use `apply` e.g. `(apply + [1 2 3 4])`
- Each parameter can be a `Number` of any type. There are many possible number types, indeed anything that extends the [`java.lang.Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) base class would suffice.
- **Inlined versions** are defined which can directly produce primitive types as a result.

There isn't an easy way to determine this from the REPL. But you might be interested in [Typed Clojure](https://github.com/frenchy64/typed-clojure) which provides a type system along with methods to define types and do corresponding type checking in Clojure. It uses a neat approach called "gradual typing", so you can add type annotations just where you need them: you don't need to assign types to the whole program at once.

Comment: "anything that extends the java.lang.Number base class would suffice."

Really? `Number` doesn't define any arithmetic methods, how does that work?

Comment: Number defines a `doubleValue` method that you can call to convert to a double and then perform double arithmetic thereafter. I believe that is what Clojure does if presented with a unknown Number subclass that isn't handled otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the Typed Clojure link -- this seems really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Clojure has the [`type`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/type) function.

```
> (type +)
clojure.core$_PLUS_

> (type clojure.core$_PLUS_)
java.lang.Class

> (type (+ 1 1))
java.lang.Long

> (type (+ 1.0 1.0))
java.lang.Double
```

So the `+` function returns either a `Long` or a `Double` depending on the arguments.

The other arithmetic functions also return different types depending on the arguments:

```
> (type (/ 3 1))
java.lang.Long

> (type (/ 3.0 1))
java.lang.Double

> (type (/ 1 3))
clojure.lang.Ratio
```

If you want to see how the function is implemented, it's as simple as [visiting the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L936). This lets you see how to define multi-arity functions.

Comment: A couple of comments: (1) `+` will return types other than Long and Double as necessary, e.g. it will return `clojure.lang.BigInt` for numeric literals that don't fit in a long. (2) Calling `type` on a compiled function class isn't very illuminating. Try `ancestors` instead, e.g. `(ancestors clojure.core$_PLUS_)`